# Switch sendmail Parameters in symfony/mailer when using symfony/messenger

Tags: symfony, sendmail, symfony-messenger, symfony-mailer

The local Development Machine uses `msmtp` for sending Mails, which works fine. BUT it does not accept `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs`, it only works with `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t`. I can see that I could change this when using other parameters for the `SendmailTransport` constructor, but actually I never create an Instance of SendmailTransport - the consumer of the Messenger does this all alone.

How can I change the Sendmail Parameters when using async Mails via Messenger?

Comment: I don't see how the Symfony Messenger is in anyway related. It will use whatever configuration it's in use for Symfony Mailer.

Comment: Yes, but at the moment i would guess that you can't switch from -bs to -t via Configuration

Answer (score 1):

`MessageHandler` receives a `TransportInterface` as a dependency in order to send the messages, so indeed you can change it via configuration. Since once messenger is installed all messages will be sent with it, you can just override the default transport directly and it will be injected into the `Handler`:

```
# config/services_dev.yaml
services:
    Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\TransportInterface: 
        class: Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\SendmailTransport
        arguments:
            - '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t'
```